# Testing Symfony2 Forms causes Could not load type "entity"

Tags: forms, testing, symfony, phpunit

I am testing a Form Type I defined for an application. During testing the form type, using symfony's TypeTestCase class a message "Could not load type "entity"" appears. What can I do to solve the problem??

```
class MyType extends AbstractType {
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->add('otherType', 'entity', array('class' => 'Bundle:OtherType'));
  }
}

class MyTypeTest extends TypeTestCase {
  public function testSth() {
    $type = new MyType();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide relevant code. Thank you

Comment: added code, sry for forgetting it!

Comment: To me it seems there isn't any error, but sure that we miss something ...

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16341149/symfony2-custom-form-type-using-entity-trying-to-test-it

Comment: how can I still test this formtype, probably using mocking??

Comment: Yes, mocking should the way, because the entity type needs doctrine, a database connection and the kernel.

Comment: Currently, Symfony supports the EntityType out of the box, but doesn't have a proper way to unit test it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15098.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I already got the same problem when testing some of my customized Types.

Here's the way I figure it out (by mocking EntityType),

**First, make sure your test class extends [TypeTestCase](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Test/TypeTestCase.php),**

```
class MyTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    // ... 
}
```

**Then, add a [preloaded extension](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/PreloadedExtension.php) to your [form factory](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Form/FormFactory.html) in order to take into account the [EntityType](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/EntityType.php)**

```
protected function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->factory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
      ->addExtensions($this->getExtensions())
      ->getFormFactory();
}
// Where this->getExtensions() returns the EntityType preloaded extension 
// (see the last step)    
}
```

**And finally, add an [Entity Type](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/EntityType.php) mock to your [preloaded extension](https://github.com/symfony/Form/blob/master/PreloadedExtension.php).**

```
protected function getExtensions()
{
    $mockEntityType = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $mockEntityType->expects($this->any())->method('getName')
                   ->will($this->returnValue('entity'));

    return array(new PreloadedExtension(array(
            $mockEntityType->getName() => $mockEntityType,
    ), array()));
}
```

**But, you may need to ...**

Mock the [registry](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineBundle/Registry.html) that [DoctrineType](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php) takes as parameter when calling its default constructor because it's used by `setDefaultOptions()` (Keep in mind that [EntityType](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/EntityType.php) extends [DoctrineType](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php)) to take into account [class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#class) and [property](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#property) options of your [Entity field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html).

Your may then need to mock the entityType as follow:

```
$mockEntityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')->getMock();

$mockRegistry = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(array('getManagerForClass'))
    ->getMock();

$mockRegistry->expects($this->any())->method('getManagerForClass')
             ->will($this->returnValue($mockEntityManager));

$mockEntityType = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType')
    ->setMethods(array('getName'))
    ->setConstructorArgs(array($mockRegistry))
    ->getMock();

$mockEntityType->expects($this->any())->method('getName')
               ->will($this->returnValue('entity'));
```

Comment: Hello, i followed what you have posted but, i got an error:  Call to protected Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::__construct() from context 'PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Generator' in /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php on line 237

Comment: @Ahmed Siouani Can you please answer the above comment

Comment: I get the same error as @skonsoft. Can you tell us possible solution for that, please?

Answer (score 0):

The Ahmed Siouani's answer is well writted and allowed me to understand how to add an `Extension` in the `TypeTestCase`.

But if you want to make an Intergration test, who is much simpler than a Unit test in this case, you can do as follow:

```
protected function getExtensions()
{
    $childType = new TestChildType();
    return array(new PreloadedExtension(array(
        $childType->getName() => $childType,
    ), array()));
}
```

As described in this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html#adding-a-type-your-form-depends-on