# How to load form types in tests

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-forms

```
<?php
namespace Tabl\VenueBundle\Tests\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;
use Tabl\VenueBundle\Entity\Venue;
use Tabl\VenueBundle\Form\VenueType;

class VenueTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{

    public function testSubmitValidData() {
        $formData = array(
            'title' => 'Hello World',
        );

        $type = new VenueType();
        $form = $this->factory->create($type);

        $object = new Venue();
        $object->setTitle('Hello World');

        // submit the data to the form directly
        $form->submit($formData);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
        $this->assertEquals($object, $form->getData());

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }
    }

}
```

I keep getting this error message:

`Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Could not load type "places_autocomplete"`

How can this be fixed? How do I load this type so I could perform a functional test on form?

`places_autocomplete` is a part of the [Ivory GMaps Bundle](https://github.com/egeloen/IvoryGoogleMapBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage/places/autocomplete.md).

VenueType.php:

```
namespace Acme\VenueBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;
use Acme\VenueBundle\Entity\Attribute;
use Acme\VenueBundle\Form\AttributeType;

class VenueType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add('address', 'places_autocomplete' , ['attr' => ['placeholder' => 'Start typing for suggestions'], 'label'=>'Location'])
            ->add('attributes', 'entity', array(
                'multiple'      => true,
                'expanded'      => true,
                'property'      => 'icon',
                'class'         => 'AcmeVenueBundle:Attribute',
            ))
            ->add('finish', 'submit');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\VenueBundle\Entity\Venue'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'venue';
    }
}
```

Comment: And where are you using this `places_autocomplete`? In the `VenueType` form? If so then try to add a `use` statement on that form as doc suggested in the link you leave, I though that is the problem

Comment: @ReynierPM Hey!I already have placed the `use` statement in the form typ file. The form in itself is working properly, but the test is the thing that's bugging me and doesn't want to work.

Comment: Seems you must [Adding a Type your Form Depends on](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html#adding-a-type-your-form-depends-on). I hope you want to mock entire behaviour of Ivory bundle Form type. So you must override the method `getExtensions` of the base class you `inherit`. See class `Symfony\Component\Form\Test\FormIntegrationTestCase`. Hope this help.

Comment: Can you post the content of `Venue`and `VenueType` class? Which version of symfony2 are you use?

Comment: Currently, Symfony supports the EntityType out of the box, but doesn't have a proper way to unit test it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/15098.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must implements the `getExtensions` methods that build the two  mocked form types used in the form: `PlacesAutocompleteType` and `EntityType`

This solutions work for me:

```
<?php


namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\Form;


use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Ivory\GoogleMapBundle\Form\Type\PlacesAutocompleteType;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\PreloadedExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Venue;
use Acme\DemoBundle\Form\VenueType;

class VenueTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{

public function testSubmitValidData() {
    $formData = array(
        'title' => 'Hello World',
    );

    $type = new VenueType();
    $form = $this->factory->create($type);

    $object = new Venue();
    $object->setTitle('Hello World');

    // submit the data to the form directly
    $form->submit($formData);

    $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());
    $this->assertEquals($object, $form->getData());

    $view = $form->createView();
    $children = $view->children;

    foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
        $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
    }
}


protected function getExtensions()
{

    // Mock the FormType: places_autocomplete

    // See Ivory\GoogleMapBundle\Tests\Form\Type\PlacesAutocompleteTypeTest
    $placesAutocompleteHelperMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Ivory\GoogleMap\Helper\Places\AutocompleteHelper')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $requestMock = $this->getMock('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request');
    $requestMock
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getLocale')
        ->will($this->returnValue('en'));

    $placesAutocompleteType = new PlacesAutocompleteType(
        $placesAutocompleteHelperMock,
        $requestMock
    );

    // Mock the FormType: entity
    $mockEntityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $mockRegistry = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $mockRegistry->expects($this->any())->method('getManagerForClass')
        ->will($this->returnValue($mockEntityManager));

    $mockEntityManager ->expects($this->any())->method('getClassMetadata')
        ->withAnyParameters()
        ->will($this->returnValue(new ClassMetadata('entity')));

    $repo = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $mockEntityManager ->expects($this->any())->method('getRepository')
        ->withAnyParameters()
        ->will($this->returnValue($repo));

    $repo->expects($this->any())->method('findAll')
        ->withAnyParameters()
        ->will($this->returnValue(new ArrayCollection()));


    $entityType = new EntityType($mockRegistry);



    return array(new PreloadedExtension(array(
        'places_autocomplete' => $placesAutocompleteType,
        'entity' => $entityType,
    ), array()));
}
}
```

Hope this help.
Let me know.

Comment: This did fix the missing `places_autocomplete`, but now I'm getting the same error for missing `entity`. (Could not load type "entity"). I tried applying [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355624/testing-symfony2-forms-causes-could-not-load-type-entity), but then I started getting: `The options "class", "expanded", "multiple", "property" do not exist. Known options are: ""`. Any idea how to fix this? Posted the VenueType.php

Comment: Hi @MJA I update my answer with the mocked entity type you use in the form.

Comment: I had a FormType with multiple entity fields, one of which used a QueryBuilder that included a where() statement.  This triggered stricter validation of the fields by the ORM query parser, so I ended up needing to mock a slew of other objects.  The query builder method chain also needed to include select() and from() for the parser's sake, where the other entity fields didn't.

Answer (score 6):

This is in addition to @Matteo's solution, in case anyone else runs into the same complications mocking the EntityType dependencies.  This gets the QueryBuilder to have the select() and from() methods called by default, which mirrors what happens on a functional kernel load and was missing on the test runs (parser was returning "`SELECT WHERE ...`").  Note that the class value in the entity field configuration array must be written out longhand, e.g. `'class' => 'AcmeBundle\Entity\MyClass'`, rather than the shorthand `'class' => 'AcmeBundle:MyClass'` just for the sake of the mock repository.

```
...

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\PostgreSqlPlatform;
use Doctrine\ORM\Configuration;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\CoreExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Validator\Type\FormTypeValidatorExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Forms;
use Symfony\Component\Form\PreloadedExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Test\TypeTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolationList;

class MyTypeCase extends TypeTestCase
{

    ...

    protected function getExtensions()
    {
        // mock entity manager
        $entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('getClassMetadata', 'getRepository'))
            ->getMock()
        ;

        // this method will be mocked specific to the class name when provided
        // by the mocked repository below - this can be generic here
        $entityManager->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getClassMetadata')
            ->will($this->returnValue(new ClassMetadata('entity')))
        ;

        $parent = $this;

        $entityManager->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getRepository')
            ->will($this->returnCallback(function($entityName) use ($parent) {

                // if ever the Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser is engaged, it will check for
                // the existence of the fields used in the DQL using the class metadata
                $classMetadata = new ClassMetadata($entityName);

                if (preg_match('/[^a-z]MyClass$/i', $entityName)) {
                    $classMetadata->addInheritedFieldMapping(array('fieldName' => 'someField', 'columnName' => 'some_field'));
                    $classMetadata->addInheritedFieldMapping(array('fieldName' => 'anotherField', 'columnName' => 'another_field'));
                }

                // mock statement
                $statement = $parent->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement')
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->getMock()
                ;

                // mock connection
                $connection = $parent->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection')
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->setMethods(array('connect', 'executeQuery', 'getDatabasePlatform', 'getSQLLogger', 'quote'))
                    ->getMock()
                ;

                $connection->expects($parent->any())
                    ->method('connect')
                    ->will($parent->returnValue(true))
                ;

                $connection->expects($parent->any())
                    ->method('executeQuery')
                    ->will($parent->returnValue($statement))
                ;

                $connection->expects($parent->any())
                    ->method('getDatabasePlatform')
                    ->will($parent->returnValue(new PostgreSqlPlatform()))
                ;

                $connection->expects($parent->any())
                    ->method('quote')
                    ->will($parent->returnValue(''))
                ;

                // mock unit of work
                $unitOfWork = $parent->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork')
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->getMock()
                ;

                // mock entity manager
                $entityManager = $parent->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
                    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                    ->setMethods(array('getClassMetadata', 'getConfiguration', 'getConnection', 'getUnitOfWork'))
                    ->getMock()
                ;

                $entityManager->expects($parent->any())
                    ->method('getClassMetadata')
                    ->will($parent->returnValue($classMetadata))
                ;

                $entityManager->expects($parent->any())
                    ->method('getConfiguration')
                    ->will($parent->returnValue(new Configuration()))
                ;

                $entityManager->expects($parent->any())
                    ->method('getConnection')
                    ->will($parent->returnValue($connection))
                ;

                $entityManager->expects($parent->any())
                    ->method('getUnitOfWork')
                    ->will($parent->returnValue($unitOfWork))
                ;

                // mock repository
                $repo = $parent->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')
                    ->setConstructorArgs(array($entityManager, $classMetadata))
                    ->setMethods(array('createQueryBuilder'))
                    ->getMock()
                ;

                $repo->expects($parent->any())
                    ->method('createQueryBuilder')
                    ->will($parent->returnCallback(function($alias) use ($entityManager, $entityName) {
                        $queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder($entityManager);
                        $queryBuilder->select($alias)
                            ->from($entityName, $alias)
                        ;
                        return $queryBuilder;
                    }))
                ;

                return $repo;
            }))
        ;

        // mock registry
        $registry = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->setMethods(array('getManagerForClass'))
            ->getMock()
        ;

        $registry->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getManagerForClass')
            ->will($this->returnValue($entityManager))
        ;

        // build the extensions
        $extensions = new PreloadedExtension(
            array(
                'entity' => new EntityType($registry),
            ),
            array()
        );

        return array($extensions);
    }
}
```

Comment: When ever I see this many mocks to test a one bit of functionality, it always feels wrong.  Maybe it's something that needs to change in Symfony to simplify form testing in future.

Answer (score 1):

This is in addition to @Matteo's solution - when You use [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery), You can get EntityType this:

```
$mockEntityManager = \Mockery::mock('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$mockRegistry = \Mockery::mock('Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry');
$mockRegistry->shouldReceive('getManagerForClass')->andReturn($mockEntityManager);
$mockEntityManager->shouldReceive('getClassMetadata')->andReturn(new ClassMetadata('entity'));
$repo = \Mockery::mock('Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository');
$mockEntityManager->shouldReceive('getRepository')->andReturn($repo);
$repo->shouldReceive('findAll')->andReturn(new ArrayCollection());
$entityType = new EntityType($mockRegistry);
```