# Symfony2: How to test FormType with custom FormTypes

Tags: php, forms, symfony, phpunit, unit-testing

I am currently trying to write a UnitTest for my Custom FormType, according to this cookbook entry: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html

Since I am using field_types in my FormType, that are introducted by a 3rd party bundle called LexikFormFilterBundle I get the following error in my unit tests:

InvalidArgumentException: Could not load type "filter_text"

I suppose this is, because the DIC is not used in unit tests, and the services that introduce these types through the bundle are not loaded automatically like they would at normal runtime.

The question is, how I mak the formFactory aware of these types in UnitTests?

Comment: Maybe you should've scrolled the doc a bit more? This part looks like a good answer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html#adding-a-type-your-form-depends-on

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059826/how-to-load-form-types-in-tests) or provide more code