# How to test a symfony form type with constructor

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-forms

i'm currently struggle with the TypeTestCase from Symfony testing a form type with an constructor. While the offical [solution](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service) registring a form as a service works well in the application, the same form type cannot be tested with TypeTestCase. Since TypeTestCase extends from FormIntegrationTestCase and extends from \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase instead from KernelTestCase. The FormFactory in TypeTestCase doesn't/can't look for forms registered as services and throw an error calling phpunit:

```
Tests\DemoBundle\Form\Type\DemoTypeTest::testSubmitValidData
Missing argument 1 for DemoBundle\Form\Type\DemoType::__construct(), called in /var/www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php on line 90 and defined
```

The only way i've currently see is not serving the dependency via constructor using the optionsResolver in the configureOptions set an required element with the setRequired method for the dependency.

Here the relevant parts from the code:

DemoType.php

```
[...]
class DemoType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
[...]
```

services.yml

```
app.form.type.demo:
    class: DemoBundle\Form\Type\DemoType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

DemoTypeTest.php

```
[...]
class DemoTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{

    protected function getExtensions()
    {
        $classMetadata = $this->getMock(ClassMetadata::class, [], [], '', false);
        /* @var ValidatorInterface|\PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject $validator */
        $validator = $this->getMock(ValidatorInterface::class);
        $validator->method('validate')->will($this->returnValue(new ConstraintViolationList()));
        $validator->method('getMetadataFor')->will($this->returnValue($classMetadata));
        return [
            new ValidatorExtension($validator),
        ];
    }

    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $formData = [
            'some' => 'data',
        ];

        $form = $this->factory->create(DemoType::class);

[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can instantiate the FormType and pass it to the form factory, as described in the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/unit_testing.html#the-basics).

You can mock the Doctrine Entity Manager, as example:

```
public function testSubmitValidData()
{
  // Mock the FormType: entity
  $em = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();

    $type = new DemoType($em);
    $formData = [
        'some' => 'data',
    ];

    $form = $this->factory->create($type);
    ...
```

A sample about mocking the Doctrine Object Stack for simulate a repo method you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059826/how-to-load-form-types-in-tests/26121508#26121508) or simply ask :)

Hope this help

Comment: Isn't there a deprecation warning (since 2.8, removed in 3.0)  by passing the factory an instantiated form type instead of the class name?

Comment: FormFactory::createNamedBuilder trigger an error since 2.8 that instaniated form types are deprecated:

        if ($type instanceof FormTypeInterface) {
            @trigger_error(sprintf('Passing type instances to FormBuilder::add(), Form::add() or the FormFactory is deprecated since version 2.8 and will not be supported in 3.0. Use the fully-qualified type class name instead (%s).', get_class($type)), E_USER_DEPRECATED);

Comment: hi @torsten so the doc is misaligned about this argument. I will search for an example of testing of form in the new way. Let me know if you find something useful

Comment: There is an issue at github faceing this problem (in)directly: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/17592

Comment: @torsten it doesn't solve the problem, it only explain why the possibility to pass instances were remvoed, but doesn't explain how to pass dependencies in tests.