# Symfony: How to test CollectionType that uses a FormType with a constructor

Tags: php, forms, symfony, unit-testing

I have a form type `StoreProfileType` that makes use of a `SocialProfileType` to create a `CollectionType` to add as many social profiles as the user likes.

Both form types, `SocialProfileType` and `StoreProfileType` have a constructor that requires the `EntityManager`.

During tests, I can pass the `EntityManager` to `StoreProfileType` but I don't know how to pass it to the embedded form type `SocialProfileType`.

This is `StoreProfileType`:

```
class StoreProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var ObjectManager */
    private $manager;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('primaryEmail', EmailType::class)
            ->add('logoUploadingFile', FileType::class, ['required' => false])
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, ['required' => false])
            ->add('address', AddressType::class, ['data_class' => AddressEmbeddable::class, 'empty_data' => new AddressEmbeddable([])])
            ->add('socialProfiles', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => SocialProfileType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['store' => $builder->getData()],
                'allow_add'  => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label' => false
            ]);

        // Transform the email string into a value object
        $builder->get('primaryEmail')->addModelTransformer(new EmailTransformer($this->manager));
    }
}
```

The FormType `SocialProfileType` is this:

```
class SocialProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    /** @var EntityManagerInterface */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $manager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('profileUrl', UrlType::class);
        $builder->get('profileUrl')->addModelTransformer(new DomainEmbeddableTransformer($this->entityManager));
        $builder->addModelTransformer(new SocialProfileTransformer($this->entityManager, $options));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => SocialProfile::class,
            'store' => Store::class,
            'company' => Company::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

I have set both forms in my `services.yml` to inject the `EntityManager` in the constructor:

```
form.type.store:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\StoreProfileType
    arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type}

form.type.social_profile:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\SocialProfileType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type}
```

All works well when rendering the forms, but I don't know how to test the form.

This is the unit test method I'm using:

```
public function testSubmitValidData()
{
    $formData = [
        'name'              => '',
        'primaryEmail'      => 'test@example.com',
        'logoUploadingFile' => '',
        'description'       => '',
    ];

    $mockStoreRepository = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityRepository::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $mockStoreRepository->method('findOneBy')->willReturn($mockStoreRepository);

    // Mock the FormType: entity
    $mockEntityManager = $this->getMockBuilder(EntityManagerInterface::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    $mockEntityManager->method('getRepository')->willReturn($mockStoreRepository);

    /** @var EntityManagerInterface $mockEntityManager */
    $type = new StoreProfileType($mockEntityManager);
    $form = $this->factory->create($type);

    $form->submit($formData);

    $this::assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

    $view     = $form->createView();
    $children = $view->children;

    foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
        $this::assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I can inject the `EntityManager` in the `StoreFormType` but I cannot inject it in the `SocialProfileType` as this is a job done directly by Symfony when rendering the form.

**How can I pass the `EntityManager` to `SocialProfileType` when testing `StoreProfileType`?.**

The error I receive is (obviously) this:

> 1) AppBundle\Tests\Unit\Form\Type\StoreTypeTest::testSubmitValidData
>   TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Form\Type\SocialProfileType::__construct() must implement
>   interface Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface, none given, called in
>   /Users/Aerendir/Documents/JooServer/_Projects/Coommercio/Apps/app-trust-back-me-www/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php
>   on line 90

**"... None given ..."**, and this is correct as I really dont' pass it... But... how can I pass it as it is embedded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load form types in tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059826/how-to-load-form-types-in-tests)