# How to mock custom form types in another form type test?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to test one custom form type, and I've followed [how to unit test your forms](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html) Symfony docs, but it doesn't specify how to mock one form type that youre using internally in the form type being tested. For example:

In my EventType.php:

```
->add('schedules', CollectionType::class, [
            'entry_type' => ScheduleType::class,
            'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
            'allow_add' => true,
        ])
```

I'm using ScheduleType, that has some dependencies, and when I run my EventType test it fails here:

```
[ArgumentCountError] Too few arguments to function App\Form\Type\ScheduleType::__construct(), 0 passed in /opt/app/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php on line 91 and exactly 3 expected
```

How can I mock ScheduleType?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/6053). You need to do something like this

```
protected function setUp(): void
{
    $this->yourDependency = $this->createMock(Dependency::class);
    $this->yourDependency->expects($this->any())
        ->method('calledFunction')
        ->willReturn([]);

    $this->yourDependency2 = $this->createMock(Dependency2::class);
    $this->yourDependency3 = $this->createMock(Dependency3::class);

    parent::setUp();
}

/** @return mixed[] */
protected function getExtensions(): array
{
    $sheduleType = new ScheduleType($this->yourDependency, $this->yourDependency2, $this->yourDependency3);

    return [
        new PreloadedExtension([$sheduleType], [])
    ];
}
```

Comment: I have a more complex use case here, I had a main form type which has a dependency and a custom form type inside it which it also has another dependency and I am not sure how I can apply this solution to my case

Comment: The accepted answer here helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26059826/how-to-load-form-types-in-tests just the case is that the inner type should be created with new and not mocked directly