# How to mock a translator service to unit test a form component that depends on it?

Tags: php, symfony, mocking, phpunit

In my Symfony app I use a form to send emails to the administrator:

```php
class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'attr' => ['placeholder' => $this->translator->trans('contact.name.placeholder')],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(["message" => $this->translator->trans('contact.name.not-blank')])
                ]
            ])
            //some other email fields 
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact_form';
    }
}
```

As you can see this class is dependant on the `translator` service which automatically done with `autowired` set to `true` in my config.

Now I need to unit test this `contactType` so following the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/unit_testing.html) I created this little test:

```php
class ContactTypeTest extends TypeTestCase
{
    public function testSubmitValidData()
    {
        $formData = [
            'subject'   => 'Subject',
            'name'      => 'Pierrick',
            'email'     => 'pierrick@domaine.com',
            'message'   => 'Team-Manager Rocks !'
        ];

        $form = $this->factory->create(ContactType::class, null);

        // submit the data to the form directly
        $form->submit($formData);

        $this->assertTrue($form->isSynchronized());

        $view = $form->createView();
        $children = $view->children;

        foreach (array_keys($formData) as $key) {
            $this->assertArrayHasKey($key, $children);
        }
    }
}
```

But when executing `./vendor/bin/simple-phpunit`I get the following error:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1) App\tests\Form\ContactTypeTest::testSubmitValidData
>   ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Form\ContactType::__construct(), 0 passed in /Users/pierrickrambaud/Sites/team-manager/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php on line 92 and exactly 1 expected

Is it possible to mock the service or alternatively is it possible to use `$this->factory->create(MyFormType::class, $object)` and give parameter to the `Type` constructor?

Comment: You need to use getExtensions https://stackoverflow.com/a/59289486/8411841

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mock custom form types in another form type test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266095/how-to-mock-custom-form-types-in-another-form-type-test)